# CSS3: z-index not working in iPad Safari

Tags: css, ipad, safari

[image: Here is the Image]

```css
.chat-main-div{
  width: 320px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #353535;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
}

.messages-appear-div{
  height: 76vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border:thin red solid;
}
.chatcomponent-chatroom-sendtext-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    background:white;
    height:76px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-main-div">
  <div class="messages-appear-div">
    <div class="chatcomponent-chatroom-sendtext-div">
      chat sending area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello,

I have a fixed div and in that I have another fixed div which is attached to bottom. When I see in iPad Safari , I see that 2nd fixed div is hiding behind the main div.

I don't know why It is appearing in iPas Safari.

Any Help Would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: try `position;relative` for z-index element

Comment: Your example doesn't contain `z-index` and your screenshot doesn't show overlapping divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.chat-main-div{
  width: 320px;
    height: 105vh;
    background-color: #353535;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}

.messages-appear-div{
  height: 105vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border:thin red solid;
}
.chatcomponent-chatroom-sendtext-div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 320px;
    bottom:0;
    background:white;
    height:76px;
    right:0
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-main-div">
  <div class="messages-appear-div">
    <div class="chatcomponent-chatroom-sendtext-div">
      chat sending area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made few changes in your existing CSS.

Hope this helps.